# Wcf service returns stream but it won't close

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a WCF service, which opens a file then returns its stream to the client. The client saves the stream content into a file using stream.CopyTo(...) then closes the returned stream.

After this 'download' step we tries to delete the file on the server using another WCF API call, but we got an 'Process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process. (mscorlib)" exception. After several minutes this "lock" disappears and the file can be deleted.

If the client side stream Close() cannot help, what should I do to get the server to release the stream and let the file delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](https://devdump.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/disposing-return-values/) you are able to dispose a return value after the operation has completed.

Do something like this:

```
public Stream GetFile(string path) 
{
    Stream fileStream = null;    

    try   
    {
        fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    OperationContext clientContext = OperationContext.Current;
    clientContext.OperationCompleted += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Dispose();
    });

    return fileStream;
}
```

Comment: Question: why is it needed:

  if (fileStream != null)

?

Answer (score 0):

The stream the client receives is *not* the same stream that the server opened and passed on to the client. Just picture a client workstation and a server, separated by the internet: If a stream is sent to the client, the client does not hold an OS handle to the physical stream on the hard disk of the server. So closing the stream the client received does nothing to release the stream on the server side.

The fact that after a few minutes the file *can* be deleted is probably because the server instance or session got disposed, releasing the stream as well.

In other words: Close (dispose) the stream on the server after sending.

Comment: I was hoping the client-side close will send back a 'message' to the wcf service about this operation :(